# Where is mysql_affected_rows() getting the last query from

Tags: php, mysql

I use mysql_affected_rows() in a php script, but the result returned is not consistent with the query that is executed directly above in the script. I do have multiple versions of the same script running, so could these php scripts be sharing the same connection?

Comment: What kind of query are you talking about that is not consistent with the return value?

Comment: If you don't believe that it's working, please provide an example to demonstrate your assertion

Comment: Indeed, can you provide us with your query and the result that made you think it's inconsistent.

Comment: There are a few oddities with mysql_affected_rows. If you do a replace then the changed rows are counted twice (once for being deleted and once for being inserted again). Further if you have multiple updates being executed in the same statement then it may not give a useful value.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It made me look harder and I found a bug in my code. I had a wrapper around query execution that was executing another query for monitoring purposes. Oops.

Answer (score -1):

> could these php scripts be sharing the same connection?

No.

> the result returned is not consistent with the query that is executed directly above in the script.

Quite contrary, it is.